# Widget Android на Keyguard'e не слушает нажатия

Tags: android, виджет

Мой виджет слушает нажатия через метод `onRecieve()`.
При создании виджета и на рабочем столе и на блокировочном экране все работает, но через некоторое время виджет на экране блокировки перестает слушать нажатия, вот что мне выдает логгер при тапах на кликабельную зону:

```
03-23 23:39:02.500 2433-2563/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=2657552045000
03-23 23:39:02.500 2433-2562/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to: action: 0x1
03-23 23:39:02.500 2433-2523/? V/WindowManager: Window{43251dd8 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=true
03-23 23:39:02.505 2433-2523/? D/LockPatternUtils: isPcwEnable = null
03-23 23:39:02.515 2433-2523/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] [s] userActivity : event: 3 flags: 0 (uid: 1000 pid: 2433)
03-23 23:39:02.520 2433-2523/? D/LockPatternUtils: isPcwEnable = null
03-23 23:39:02.520 2433-2523/? V/WindowManager: Window{43251dd8 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=true
```

При чем виджет не перестает работать вообще, проходит время, он обновляется и работает и эта история повторяется) Такой же виджет только на рабочем столе работает нормально.